# How can I count Integers in a List of String. Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell

There is a list of String ["f", "1", "h", "6", "b", "7"].

How can I count Int in this list?

Now I have this algorithm but it's not so good.

```
import Data.Char
let listOfStrings = ["f", "1", "h", "6", "b", "7"]
let convertedString = "f1h6b7"
let listOfInt = map (\x -> read [x]::Int) (filter (\x -> isDigit x) convertedString)
length listOfInt
Prelude> 3
```

Besides, I can't convert listOfStrings to one string. This algorithm doesn't even work properly

Can you help me with optimization?

Comment: You want to count the `String`s in the list that are representations of integers (in base 10?), did I understand that correctly? Only non-negative integers or also negative?

Comment: Yes. I want to count Strings that are representations of integers. They may be negative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Use `reads :: Reads Int` (this expression is just `reads :: String -> [(Int, String)]` in disguise) to test whether a string is a representation of an integer value:

```
isNumber :: String -> Bool
isNumber s = case (reads s) :: [(Int, String)] of
    [(_, "")] -> True
    _         -> False
```

Why [`reads`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3areads)? Because it returns additional information about parsing process from which we can conclude if it was successful. `read :: Int` would just throw an exception.

2) then filter a list of strings with it and take its length:

```
intsCount :: [String] -> Int 
intsCount = length . filter isNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic principle is

- count the items in a list with a given property

That's solved by some `Prelude` functions quite easily:

```
countItemsWith :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
countItemsWith property list = length $ filter property list
```

All that remains is to find a good expression to determine whether a `String` is the representation of an integer. We could write our own test, but we can also re-use a `Prelude` function for that,

```
isIntegerRepresentation :: String -> Bool
isIntegerRepresentation s = case reads s :: [(Integer,[Char])] of
                             [(_,"")] -> True
                             _        -> False
```

Answer (score 0):

`concat` concatenates multiple lists, so `concat listOfStrings` will result in `"f1h6b7"`.
If you only want to count positive integers, you could try something along the lines of

```
countInts (x:xs) = if isDigit x then 1 + countInts xs else countInts xs
```

where `(x:xs)` is a pattern for a list with head element `x` and a tail of `xs`. (So this will work for `convertedString` because it is a list of characters `[Char]` *but not* for `listOfStrings` because it is actually `[String]` which can be expanded to `[[Char]]`).

What is the actual input you've got? `listOfStrings` or `convertedString`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be rewritten as:

```
import Data.Char

let listOfStrings = ["f", "1", "h", "6", "b", "7"]
let convertedString = concat listOfStrings
let listOfInts = map digitToInt (filter isDigit convertedString)

length listOfInts
Prelude> 3
```

To go from a list of strings to just a single string, just use `concat`. Concat takes a list of lists, and returns a single list, with all the elements of the lists after each other, and since a string is a list of `Char`s, `concat` in this case takes a list of lists of `Char`, and returns a single list of `Char`, (aka a string).

The filter is simplified from using `\x -> isDigit x` to just `isDigit`. This is exactly the same function.

I read the digits using `digitToInt` instead of `\x -> read [x] :: Int`

Notice that if you only want to find the number of digits in `convertedString`, you can do:

```
let listOfDigits = filter isDigit convertedString

length listOfDigits
Prelude> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the best answer for you will be

```
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.Char (isNumber)
countNumb l = foldl' (\x y -> x+1) 0 (filter isNumber l)
```

here we check if char is number and count them

Ps. This will work for `['f', '1', 'h', '6', 'b', '7']`.

Answer (score 0):

I find it often useful to convert `Bool` to 0 or 1 using `fromEnum`:

```
import Data.Char

countInts = sum . map (fromEnum . isNumber) . concat
```